# How to type Greek letters on mathematica.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, formatting

I usually ask questions on this website, and many of them contain Greek letters in the code part. For instance:

```
\[CapitalTheta]=0
```

After a while, someone edits the question and, magically, the capital theta becomes a real capital theta, formatted correctly.  I am always bewildered by this, and searched for a way to do it, but haven't found it yet. Can anyone solve this intricate mystery for me?

Comment: This should be moved to meta.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb

Comment: @thedude You can vote to migrate: Close -> Off topic -> Belongs on other site -> Meta

Comment: You can also use the converter at http://steampiano.net/msc/

Comment: @Szabolcs One can only vote to close (migrate) with 3,000+ rep; so it is *flag* for thedude likely?

Comment: I simply use the foreign keyboard option (Greek) on my Mac Pro.  Like this:  π.

Comment: @gwr You are right.  I misread the reputation threshold list, I was looking at the threshold for voting to migrate one's own question.

Comment: @David I do too, but that's not so trivial unless you're quite used to the layout ...

Comment: @Szabolcs:  1) Go to the top menu bar on the Mac with the American flag and select the language desired (e.g., *Greek*).  2) In the same menu, select *Show Keyboard Viewer*.